# Best way to validate uniqueness of a field Mangoose Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

When registering a new user, I want to check email for uniqueness. I am using body parser to make sure all fields are not empty, but how am I to check that the input email is not used by anyone else and to immediately output the message for a user?

The technology stack is Node.js, mongoose, body-parser module, mongodb

Here's the route file:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
  let name = req.body.name;
  let email = req.body.email;    

  req.checkBody('name', 'Name field is empty!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email field is empty!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email format').isEmail();      

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
      errors:errors
    });
  } else {
    let newUser = new User({
      name: name, 
      email: email
    });
```

After looking through similar questions, I found a way to use a pre save in my model file, but I don't know how to sisplay the error to the user as a part of the `errors` array (see above)

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve both from the Mongoose model and the Register() method.

The user model should be like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },    
},
{
    timestamps: true
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

This will ensure that emails are unique. Then at the register method, you do this:

```
exports.register = function(req, res, next){
  let name = req.body.name;
  let email = req.body.email;    
  User.findOne({email: email}, function(err, existingUser){
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        if(existingUser){                        
        return res.status(422).json('Email address is already registered.');            
        }
        else {
          var user = new User({
              username : username,
              email: email,
              password: password
          });

          user.save(function(err, user){
              if(err){
                  return next(err);
              }
              var userInfo = setUserInfo(user);
              res.status(201).json({
                  token: 'JWT ' + generateToken(userInfo),
                  user: userInfo
              })
          });
        }
    });
  }
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use

`router.post('/register', function(req, res){
 
});` as in your code above instead of `exports.register = function(req, res, next){ }`

Comment: thank you! You really helped me, but is it okay if I use `router.post('/register'` instead of `exports.register`?